# MySQL multiple column relationships between 2 tables

Tags: mysql, relationships

I have this problem in a table where there are 4 columns which include terms describing the product. I want to make this terms editable (and you can add more) in my app and there are 4 groups of them obviously. I created a table who has all these terms altogether but the product table will have to create 4 relationships with the ID of the terms table.

Is this a good solution?

The main reason I don't want to make 4 different tables for the terms is because there aren't many of them and as the app progresses we might have even more different term groups, thus adding many small tables cluttering the database.

Any suggestion?

Update #1: Here is my current schema https://i.stack.imgur.com/twndq.png

Comment: if you could somehow show a schema of your current database, that would help a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try a mapping table:

```
apputamenti(id, ...)

term_map (apputamenti_id, term_id) 

terms (id, text, type)
```

So you can add as many terms as you want.

Or if you want to specify the mapping with one more field, change:

```
term_map (apputamenti_id, term_id, map_type)
```

so you can use an enum for `map_type` like `enum(tipologia, feedback, target)` or whatever your original fields where

Comment: yeah should be fine, changed my answer to your table names

Comment: it'd still have 4 relationships between appuntamenti and term_map, wouldn't it?

Comment: no, you can drop the original fields in apputamenti. i changed my answer to add your old field names to the map

Answer (score 1):

Have a product table and a `terms (product_id, terms_name, terms_description)` which will allow you to add as many or as little terms for each product as you want. You just need to retrieve all terms from the terms table with a particular product id.

Comment: so your relation of `product <-> terms` is `n <-> m` (a product can have multiple terms, and a term can have multiple products) ?

Comment: @x4rf41 i updated the post with the current schema, and yes i think that might be the relationship, i might have done it wrong in the schema

Comment: the terms table makes sense as a stand alone only if you count on re-using a term for more appuntamenti. Otherwise the structure i described above should do.